# Javascript validation on dynamic inputs and combining inputs with some logic

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

In a form (named **createform**) many inputs are created dynamically by clicking on add button (from 0 to any number for each kind of input). 
The problem I'm having is the validation of the inputs that were created dynamically, because there is a complex logic behind it.

**THE SCENARIO**

I can have several different inputs:

- brand
- model
- country
- region

The first of them is called brand1, model1, country1 and region1, then adding others they will be called for instance brand2... brand50

In the starting scenario there will be only brand1 and model1. The country and region inputs are added only by clicking on a button.

**THE VALIDATION CONDITION**

*I have to submit the form only in two cases:*

1. If there is **at least one** brand + one model where both of them are not empty (any brand and any model, so it can also be brand5 and model12)
2. If there is **at least one** brand + country + region not empty (all of them not empty, same logic than before)

I made the following validation function which works good if I assume that I just have the first brand,model,country and region (so brand1,model1,country1 and region1).

**THE CODE**

```
function validateForm() {
    var brand = document.forms["createform"]["brand1"].value;
    var model = document.forms["createform"]["model1"].value;
    if (document.forms["createform"]["country1"] === undefined) {
        var country = "";
    } else {
        var country = document.forms["createform"]["country1"].value;
    }
    if (document.forms["createform"]["country1"] === undefined) {
        var region = "";
    } else {
        var region = document.forms["createform"]["region1"].value;
    }
    if ((brand != "") && (model != "")) {
        alert("Send");
        return true;
    } else if ((brand != "") && (country != "") && (region != "")) {
        alert("Send");
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("Impossible to send");
        return false;
    }
}
```

For better reading of the code I added return true even if it is not necessary.

The main problem is that it is impossible to know how many inputs there will be of every different kind. I was thinking about trying by checking if the inputs are starting with brand,model,country or region but I don't know how to cross my controls in my validation function with all the possible results.

Do you guys have any idea of how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a way to access all your brand and model elements by the start of their name.

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("form[id='createform']>input[id^='brand']");
```

This will give you an array (instead of your single valued variable) which you can loop through looking for your values.

The nifty querySelectorAll accepts selectors which can narrow your search to all matching elements. In the example, it gets all input elements within a form named "createform" which start with (^=) "brand".

Comment: so with querySelectorAll is it possible to check if one of those brands are not empty or it just collects the id of the inputs starting with brand?

Comment: Yes. It's simply an array of your elements.
So you could do a loop like:
for(var i = 0; i<brands.length; i++) {
     if(brands[i].value !== "") return true;
}

Answer (score 0):

```
var brandelements = document.querySelectorAll("#createform select[name^='brand'] option:checked:not([value=''])");
```

This is the best way to get all the values of a select (you can easily change with a normal input) that are not empty.